# Excel VBA Code Writing Multiple SQL Records

Tags: sql, excel, vba, connection

The below code is intended to do this:

(1) Running the refreshDataConnections macro to run in the next 6 seconds (6 seconds being the timerStart variable)

(2) The call to flag1On is made, where a SQL Connection is created. The goal is to insert a record into the table.

(3) The last call is back to the refreshDataConnections macro to reset the timer to 6 seconds from Now(), and to keep the entire macro on a 6 second repeat.

The issue experienced is that when flag1On  is run, it inserts the record perfectly into the SQL table, but then inserts another record 6 seconds later. I've experimented with this, and found that whatever the timerStart variable is, the second record is always written that many seconds after the initial.

(Example SQL Data Current Results)

OneOrZero | User | RunDt

```
1          User      3-12-15 12:00:20PM
1          User      3-12-15 12:00:14PM
1          User      3-12-15 12:00:13PM
1          User      3-12-15 12:00:07PM
1          User      3-12-15 12:00:06PM
1          User      3-12-15 12:00:00PM
```

Is there anything from the below code that would cause the SQL code to be written twice each time the entire code runs, once on time and once on whatever the timerStart variable is set to?

My goal is to have the below data

OneOrZero | User | RunDt

```
1          User      3-12-15 12:00:30PM
1          User      3-12-15 12:00:24PM
1          User      3-12-15 12:00:18PM
1          User      3-12-15 12:00:12PM
1          User      3-12-15 12:00:06PM
1          User      3-12-15 12:00:00PM
```

Below is the code.

```
Option Explicit
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const timerStart = 6 ' five seconds
Public Const subTarget = "refreshMirror"  ' the name of the procedure to run
Public flag As Boolean

Public Sub refreshDataConnections()
    On Error Resume Next
RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, timerStart)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=subTarget, _
        Schedule:=True
End Sub

Public Sub refreshMirror()
    On Error Resume Next
    Call flag1On
    Call refreshDataConnections
End Sub

Sub flag1On()
Dim item As String, thisConn As New ADODB.Connection

thisConn.Open ("Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=(password); _ 
    Persist Security Info=True;User ID=(UserID); _
        Initial Catalog=srd;Data Source=(Table); _
            Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True; _
                Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=(WorkstationID); _ 
                  Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False")

item = "Insert into [(Table)].[dbo].[Table1] _ 
    (OneOrZero, networkID,rundt) Values(1,(User),'" & _ 
        Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS") & ".000')"
    thisConn.Execute (item)
    thisConn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `flagDecision1` code? How do you start `refreshDataConnections`?

Comment: Sorry about that; I had the items mislabeled. I manually begin the refreshDataConnections sub myself, and from there it automatically runs when the timer calls it. I fixed the flagDecision1 code; it's all referenced back to the flag1On sub.

Answer (score 0):

Ok; so this whole method was sabotaged by myself due to keeping the "Background Data Refresh" button active on the data connection properties. Once this was turned off, problem solved!